# Motivation behind the Bohr-Mollerup Theorem relating the Gamma function

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ho.history-overview, special-functions, gamma-function

In [Wikipedia,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem) it states about the Bohr-Mollerup Theorem:

> The theorem was first published in a textbook on complex analysis, as **Bohr and Mollerup thought it had already been proved**.

If anyone knows, I'd very much like to know the source of this claim, so that I could check it myself/read more about it. This claim makes me think there could have been - perhaps according to their "thought" - that there was already a unique characterization of Gamma function before them. Is this true, or were Bohr & Mollerup the first one who gave a description of the characterization since the birth of Gamma function?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Not an answer, but the reference in question is: Harald August Bohr and Johannes Mollerup, _Lærebog i Matematisk Analyse_ III: Grænseprocesser, Jul. Gjellerups Forlag (1922), 149–155. If you are from the USA or have a USA VPN, you can access the original text at https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=njp.32101065821660&seq=155.